# Loading items from service into a single select

Tags: user-interface, ibm-bpm

I am using IBM BPM V8.5.7. I want to use a single select to select an item which are retrieved via a service. The problem is that the service returns 10k+ items and I currently use a search function. What I want to achieve basically is to search in the single select dropdown and whilst doing that it must fire the service and return the search results.

I have managed to get the search function working properly but searching through so many items slows down BPM. I've tried using a piece of code but that just cleared the items once the service was called

Comment: 10k items is almost impossible to load because browser restrictions... I don't think it's related to IBM BPM... When you filter, how many items are you returning?

Answer (score 0):

Your DB-Select probably looks somewhat like this:

```
SELECT name, value FROM YOURTABLE
```

This will stress your ibm-control (are you using the classic controls or something else like apex)?
Try to limit the result-set from your SQL-Query. One example could be:

```
SELECT name, value FROM YOURTABLE  FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY
```

(be aware this is DB2 style) - in MS SQL this looks like this:

```
SELECT TOP(100) name, value FROM YOURTABLE
```

Comment: I do not work with the database side. In the coachview I have a textbox where I would like to enter the phrase to search. The single select dropdown calls a service which lists the items. Basically I'd like to enter characters in the textbox that would perform the search in the single select. I've tried using a variable for the service input data but when I'm searching using the textbox it just populates all the service items in the dropdown

Comment: You probably have to edit the underlying service to change the results. Have you tried the IBM Process Designer (eclipse) for viewing the service?